# Is there a way to lookup a jsonb column by its values

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, sql-like, jsonb

I have a table, `test`, in postgres 12 with a jsonb column, `data_col`, that has many different keys and values.
My requirement is to select * from that table where value matches a string.

for example, the table has data as below

```
id   some_value  data_col
---------------------------------------------------------------       
11   2018        {"a": "Old Farm"}
12   2019        {"b": "My house is old", "c": "See you tomorrow"}
13   2020        {"d": "The old house", "a": "Very Green", "e": "Olden days"}
```

As you can see, there are many different keys and so its not practical to lookup like the examples on the web suggests i.e col_name->>'Key'

I am looking to write a sql with a where clause to give me all rows that have the string "old" in it.

something like:

```
select * from test where data_col ILIKE '%old%'
```

should give me

```
11, 2018, Old Farm
12, 2019, My house is old
13, 2020, Olden days
```

Comment: What if there are two values in the object that contain "old"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses `jsonb_each()`:

```
select t.*, x.*
from test t
cross join lateral jsonb_each(t.data_col) x 
where x.value ilike '%old%'
```

Note that this multiplies the rows if an object contains "old" more than once. To avoid that, you can use `exists` instead:

```
select t.*
from test t
where exists (
    select 1
    from jsonb_each(t.data_col) x
    where x.val ilike '%old%'
)
```

Or if you want to aggregate all the matched values in one column:

```
select t.*, x.*
from test t
cross join lateral (
    select string_agg(x.val, ',') as vals
    from jsonb_each(t.data_col) x
    where x.val ilike '%old%'
) x
where x.vals is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Postgres 12, you can use a SQL/JSON path function:

```
select id, some_value, 
       jsonb_path_query_first(data_col, '$.* ? (@ like_regex "old" flag "i")') #>> '{}' 
from data
```

The `#>>` operator is only there to convert the scalar JSON value into text (as there is no direct cast from `jsonb` to `text` that would remove the double quotes)

If there are potentially more values with the substring, you can use `jsonb_path_query_array()` to all of them as an array (obviously you need to remove the `#>>` then)